# 5G NR Network Collision Avoidance

Tags: radio, interference

I'm looking for a technical explanation or a specification that explains exactly how 5G NR collision avoidance will work. I was watching a talk from the Mobile World Conference in Shanghai two years ago (2018) and it appears that centralized transmission scheduling may be a part of the standard - here is a timestamped link to the panel member that references this:

[Steve Greaves addresses 802.11ay collision avoidance](http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=pxs7Q-vvxHI&t=19m35s)

To quote:

> If you look at what Facebook are doing with AY they are trying to get coordination & synchronization across the
>   whole network. Once you have that capability what you can do is you
>   can manage interference. You can control the scheduling of
>   transmissions such that you can deal with the dense urban deployments
>   which are interference limited.

I can't find a standard or explanation for this exact thing within 5G so I was hoping someone could point me in the right direction.

**Note:** I am not intimately familiar with 5G and am not sure what parts of the "standard" for 5G have been defined. For a long time there was no standard at all. *Also* please let me know if there is a better community for this question.

Comment: 5G base station ALWAYS transmits frames even if no cellphone (rather any 5G User Equipment) connects to it. BS owns the synchronization by time synchronizing the frame duration and telling each UE when to transmit. So collision is minimized. In 802.11ay (it is not a cellular standard but for bursty data like WiFi), each user equipment before transmitting has to probe the medium for any other transmission (called CA/CD algorithm and its advanced versions).

Comment: @jithin Thank you! That makes more sense now thinking about it. I'm surprised the panelist even mentioned it. I'm more familiar with WiFi and its related technologies than anything cellular.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

IEEE 802.11 is not related to 5G NR, so consideration for WLAN networks following 802.11ay don't apply to cellular infrastructure.

I don't know what "ad-hoc" modi 5G NR brings; I don't think it's any.

So, 5G doesn't do *any* collision avoidance, because it's not a problem it has: it's a cellular standard that defines that the basestation / cellular infrastructure *defines* who sends when, where. The mobile network operators *own* the spectrum, so there's by definition no uncooperative users.

Generally, whereas interference mitigation is in fact a non-negligible topic for coordinated microwave networks, with these deci- to centimeter waves still taking many non-optical paths and receiver sensitivity being high enough for that to create "unwantedly far reach", you can basically ignore that for cellular mmWave applications, where you can be pretty sure that you, as the owner of the used spectrum, will have a relatively easy time making sure that your own femtocell base stations don't lead to mutual interference: The propagation is pretty much optical, so, the potential numbers of base stations a single handset might reach is pretty limited by lines of sight and a pretty small radius.